# Warning: "Name 'xxx' can be undefined" in Python

Tags: python, pycharm, undefined, warnings

I'm trying to run someone else's code in Python and I have this warning:

> Name 'embedding_vector' undefined.

```
## Making an embeddings matrix from embeddings vector ##

embedding_dim = 100
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((max_words, embedding_dim))

for word, i in word_index.items():
   if i < max_words:
       embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
   if embedding_vector is not None:
       embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
```

These two lines have the warning.

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: you have an error in your logic. the first if statement might not always be satisfied, therefore `embedding_vector` in not assigned a value, which means your second if statement will fail as `embedding_vector` effectively does not exist

Comment: Note: The image became dominating by a later change, and ***the error message is actually included*** (except the actual name, `embedding_vector`). Thus [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/) does not apply.

Comment: *"Name 'embedding_vector' undefined."* seems to be out of sync with the image. Or are they in two different places?

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `embedding_vector` before the loop:

```py
embedding_dim = 100
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((max_words, embedding_dim))
embedding_vector = None

for word, i in word_index.items():
  # ...
```

From static code analysis point of view there are conditions when `embedding_vector` is not defined (i.e. `i < max_words` is always false) though with real data it can be impossible.

Comment: Now that I've changed some other parts but not this, I'm getting the User warning which says, " \venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\legacy\adam.py:117: UserWarning: The `lr` argument is deprecated, use `learning_rate` instead.
  super().__init__(name, **kwargs)"
Any Idea how to fix that?

Comment: @Ted_k this obviously comes from the library you are using which means that this should be a new question (with [mre]). P.S. If any of the provided answers for this question works for you - please mark it as accepted one (checkmark to the left) and upvote all the useful ones.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm expressed by your code looks weird to me. My feeling is that the assignment of the vector to a row of the matrix should be done only if this vector has just received a value, so the indent should be like this:

```py
for word, i in word_index.items():
    if i < max_words:
        embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
        if embedding_vector is not None:
            embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
```

It’s even possible (but less probable) that the `embeddings_index.get(word)` call never returns `None` so that you can remove the last conditional. This would mean that the author of the code thought that `is not None` comprised “being undefined” and wrote this test for this case, but it’s wrong.

Otherwise, as given by others, the simple manner to get rid of the warning while keeping the very same logic is to initialize `embedding_vector` to `None` before the `for` loop:

```py
embedding_vector = None
```

Generally, I don’t like linters very much, but here, the linter is right: this code is weird.

Maybe the idea is that the values for `i` will be sorted in ascending order, e.g. start from 0 and increase 1 by 1. And when it has gone above some `max_words` value (which is the number of rows in the matrix), nothing more should be done. Then it would be more efficient to simply quit the loop at this time:

```py
for word, i in word_index.items():
    if i >= max_words:
        break
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
```

Comment: Now that I've changed some other parts but not this, I'm getting the User warning which says, " \venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\legacy\adam.py:117: UserWarning: The `lr` argument is deprecated, use `learning_rate` instead.
  super().__init__(name, **kwargs)" 
I have no clue how to figure that out since this is the first time I'm suing keras.